# Tear when not expected after re-sizing the texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In certain circumstances, there is a desire to expand a texture when the user is zooming into an image until the shortest edge fills the entire screen (as seen with standard galleries).  However, the input to the OpenGL shader is a matrix from an ImageView, so certain translations need to be put into place as well as corrective calculations for different spaces.

***EDIT:***

The vertex shader code is simplistic and is as follows:

```
private final String vertexShader_ =
        "attribute vec4 a_position;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 a_texCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_Position = a_position;\n" +
        "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord.xy;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

where a_position references verticesData_ below.  When loading onto the screen, the position of the image is accurate based upon calculations from the display width and a portion of the screen that is occupies.

Additionally, I have the following fragment shader code:

```
private final String fragmentShader_ =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n" +
        "uniform mat3 transform;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  vec2 uv = (transform * vec3(v_texCoord, 1.0)).xy;\n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, uv );\n" +
        "}\n";
```

where the input of the mat3 transform is input that is coming from an ImageView.  Essentially, there is an ImageView underneath the OpenGLSurfaceView.  It is a much lower resolution image and when the user swipes, the SurfaceView is hidden and the ImageView is beneath it at the same position that the user was in the SurfaceView.

However, later on when I want to expand upon this texture, I am finding myself will unexpected results.

When panning back and forth, the screen moves where it is expected to move.  So, the translation in the x and y coordinates from the matrix are coming across ok.  However, when zooming in, the image is tearing.  It is only tearing when the bounds of the texture have grown beyond the screen dimensions.  As can be seen below, the height is not introducing extra pixels when growing, but the width is tearing as it progresses.

In order to pass an appropriate matrix, the values from the ImageView to the OpenGL SurfaceView were inverted and transposed, since the space required it for an appropriate conversion.  A scale factor is passed into the a listener that the Activity is listening in on.

```
@Override
public void onTranslation(float imageScaleF, float[] matrixTranslationF)
{   
    currentScaleForImage_ = imageScaleF;
    //If we are currently using the entire screen, then there is not need anymore to resize the texture itself.
    if(surfaceViewWidth_ * imageScaleF > displayViewWidth_ && surfaceViewHeight_ * imageScaleF > displayViewHeight_)
    {

    }
    else //Expand the size of the texture to be displayed on the screen.
    {
        maximumScaleForImage_ = imageScaleF;
        photoViewRenderer_.updateTextureSize(imageScaleF);
        photoSurfaceView_.requestRender();
    }
    matrixTranslationF = updateTranslationBasedOnTextureSize(matrixTranslationF);
    photoViewRenderer_.updateTranslationOfTexture(matrixTranslationF);
    photoSurfaceView_.requestRender();
}
```

But, with the following code above, the portion of the image that scrolls is always cut short, and if I attempt to correct it based upon the scale by uncommenting the line there for updating the Translation, it causes tears.  So, it seems as though at this point, the user below has gotten me into a better position with their input, but I am still a single step away and I think that it is within this function.  The following now updated code below has made the corrections necessary in order to provide an appropriate translation between the matricies in the ImageView and the OpenGL texture/coordinates.

```
private float[] updateTranslationBasedOnTextureSize(float[] matrixTranslationsF)
    { 
        if(scaleDirection_ == ScaleDirection.WIDTH)
        {
            matrixTranslationsF[0] = matrixTranslationsF[0] * maximumScaleForImage_;
        }
        else if(scaleDirection_ == ScaleDirection.HEIGHT)
        {
            matrixTranslationsF[4] = matrixTranslationsF[4] * maximumScaleForImage_;
        }

        return matrixTranslationsF;
    }
```

I was causing tearing in the photographs in the first iteration as seen below. Or it was clipping the photograph due to improper conversions between the two spaces.

[image: Before update to texture size with user interaction]
[image: After update texture size]

The width seems to be maintained, so it suggests to me that maybe something happens with values outside the standard bounds, but I am not sure what to try.

Comment: Texture coordinate ranges are not actually (-1,-1) - (1,1). They are normalized into (0,0) - (1,1). Anything outside of this range is subject to your texture wrap mode, and in this case it looks like you are using `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. If you are expecting them to be in the range of (-1,-1) to (1,1) this could explain some strange behaviour - that coordinate space is actually for post-projected vertices, immediately before they are mapped to the viewport.

Comment: I am not sure what the behaviour you are trying to produce here is. If you are panning, then in desktop GL you might use `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` and set a border color of black, of course this clamp mode does not exist in GLES. You would have to implement it manually in your fragment shader by detecting out-of-range texture coordinates.

Comment: I'd love to win your bounty but I don't know what more you're looking for.  Think of this.. you can zoom in on a picture either by scaling up the width and height, scaling up using matrix math, OR by scaling DOWN the texture coordinates. The formulas I gave you in my answer are what I use in my app to zoom in/out and pan around on images.  Like I said in my comments.. my answer is correct.  Your texture coordinates are out of bounds - as both me and Andon have said. But it seems like you're looking for something else - not sure what.

Comment: In fact, I need to scale using multiple of those.  And that is where its a bit tricky for me; especially since I don't use OpenGL outside small moments such as these.  I need to scale up the texture so that it fills the screen, but then from there on I need to use the matrix math from an Android ImageView to match with a matrix that I am passing in to the OpenGL code. Of course, there is matrix changes during the texture re-sizing as well to compensate for.  And finding that correlation between the latest texture size and the input of the matrix is causing me problems.

Answer (score 2):

This streaking is happening because you have the texture wrap set to clamp to edge.  You have something like:

```
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```

GL_REPEAT is the default and will repeat the image.  But you're looking to not have any "effect" at the bottom. This bottom is happening because of your MATH.  You are getting the streaking only on the bottom and not the sides.  As someone said in the comment you're vertex range isn't correct.  The min and max are 0 and 1.. not -1 and 1.  So at the bottom of your picture it's streaking because you're calculating a texture coordinate number out of the 0-1 bounds and probably getting in to the <0 area or the >1 area.  When the texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_fragmentTexCoord0) gets a texture coordinate outside of the 0-1 range it's going to fall on that WRAP_S / WRAP_T setting to know what value to give.  It's repeating the edge pixel because you have GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

Your actual problem though isn't this setting. It's that you are calculating an S or T outside of the range to begin with. That's not good form cause even if you were writing black in there it's wasted cycles on the fragment shader and will slow down your app.  Basically, your formulas are wrong.

As for your zooming in math... it's math.  You'll have to work it out for whatever you're trying to do.  (Or ask for help.)  You could do something like this, which is a simplified version of what I'm doing in my new photo editing app:

```
    GLfloat aspect = photo.width / photo.height;
    if (aspect > 1) {
      displayWidth = panelWidth;
      displayHeight = panelWidth/aspect;
    }
    else {
      displayHeight = panelHeight;
      displayWidth = panelHeight*destAspect;
    }
```

Where panelWidth and panelHeight are the size of the area you're displaying your photo - which could be the full screen or something smaller. Then build your vertex based on the display height and width.  If you zoom in beyond the size of the panel you'll need to then do a crop to keep the image inside the panel, both by reducing the display width or height (which ever one is too large) and also changing your texture coordinates to match.  This is very rough but something like this:

```
GLfloat sSize = (destSMax-destSMin) / panelZoom;
GLfloat tSize = (destTMax-destTMin) / panelZoom;

displaySMin = destSMin + panelPanX/coreTextureSize;
displayTMin = destTMin + panelPanY/coreTextureSize;

displaySMax = displaySMin + sSize;
displayTMax = displayTMin + tSize;
```

Then of course build your vertex data, use matrix math to move the square where you want it, and draw it.

I recommend rethinking your approach to using something more like what I'm doing above.  Don't remove a percentage of the photo when it goes off screen.  Instead calculate what is going to be seen and build your data based on that.

EDIT - Also, I realized my code is ios code and this is an android question.  Same concept applies though.  The glTexParameteri call might be slightly different and it might be float instead of GLfloat.

Comment: Sorry it was late when I wrote the answer and I had it backwards.. clamp to edge does do what you're showing and so I corrected my answer.  Still the math to calculate the texture coords in the first place are where you should look.  This is your problem.

Comment: Sounds like it's not working if it's still showing the repeated pixels at the bottom.  A texture coordinate of -1 is absolutely outside of bounds and will return a color value based on how you have the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP set.  With CLAMP_TO_EDGE it will "tear" like you've shown above.  With REPEAT you'll see the image be "tiled" and repeated.

When you zoom in on the photo - it seems like what you would want it so constrain the image to not scroll up to where you could see black.  But it's your app.  Technically my answer though is correct.

Comment: Unsure about your "-1 is absolutely out of bounds".  Those coordinates are used to display the original image in order for the texture to take up only the portion of the screen that I want at the beginning (centered and scaled to proportion).  After re-sizing from the edges based on the aspect ratio of the image the texture looks fine using those. Before using those vertices the texture was not displayed in the right location.  I don't touch those vertices anymore after growth to max screen size, which seems to be working just fine. The rest where problems occur is fragment shader code.

Comment: The code above for 'updateTranslationBasedOnTextureSize' was an attempt to make up for an effect that was going on that I saw without it.  Without that call, while the texture is growing, the matrix is causing a stretch of the image until the texture stops growing.  Then the image is being scaled and grown properly.  This modification didn't provide the solution that I wanted however.  If, an image takes up most or all of the screen size however, the code works perfectly; so something is up while the texture is growing ...  probably matrix compensations that I have to deal with.

Comment: It actually only stretches in the direction that the texture is growing without 'updateTranslationBasedOnTextureSize'.  Which in turn causes clipping of that side of the image at the edge.  That's why I was trying to compensate in that method. The clamp errors only come into place after I try and find valid compensations with this method on place to alter the matrix. With an image that never stops growing until x2 zoom maximum has been achieved, it seems to clip exactly half the image in that direction.

Comment: However, this morning after suggestions and input from you I have achieved a successful zoom/pan that I now have for various size images on top of the ImageView using its matrix as input, I might not have resolved this problem without your initial comments and questioning of me, so its appreciated.  I'll update above in the question what had worked for me; thanks badweasel.

Comment: Are you sure that maybe the -1 is not a texture coordinate but a vertex coordinate?  On my photo editing app (due out in a few weeks) I fought over and over with scaling, aspect, panning issues. I'd get everything working fine and then suddenly it doesn't work right on another image size or aspect ratio.  I might do a "The math of..." blog when it's all over.  Thanks for the bounty!